# Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions while attempting to activate DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I try to scaffold an MVC Controller with views and Entity Framework like this:

[image: scaffolding controller window]

I get this error:

[image: error window]

This is my `DbContext` class:

```cs
namespace Infrastructure
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Owner> owners { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProtoFile> protoFiles { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProtoFile>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>().HasData(
                new Owner
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),  
                    Avatar = "avatar.jpg",
                    FullName = "Mohammad AlMohammad AlMahmoud",
                    Profile = ".NET Full Stack Developer"
                }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls post Owner and Protofile classes too.

Comment: namespace Core.Entities
{
    public class Owner : EntityBase
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public string Profile { get; set; }

        public string Avatar { get; set; }

        public Adress? Adress { get; set; }

    }

}
namespace Core.Entities
{
    public class ProtoFile : EntityBase
    {
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }


    }



}

Comment: I tested with your codes and in my case there's no error. The error shows that your codes get wrong with the dependency injection of your Dbcontext.Are you using the default IServiceProvider?

Comment: in program class i used this provider    var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var configration=provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
var name = configration.GetValue<string>("MyProtoFileDb");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally fixed it by adding a [IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory)

```
public class BloggingContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<BloggingContext>
{
    public BloggingContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db");

        return new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: this work with me too , thanks !

Comment: how did u fix it ur simply moving the hard codding else where?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this code to your  program class (if you use net 6)

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

or if your are using net 5 or lower, add the same to a startup class

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(.....
```

and remove

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
```

Comment: I did this already...but the app didn't work

Comment: i am using .Net 6 , and i did that and isn't work

Comment: Make sure you add it to the services before calling `var app = builder.Build();`. I had it wrong way around and it resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding this code into DataContext class

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder DataContext)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test");
    }
```

and it was solved, but after generation the code i have some problem when i run the application, so i remove it and the app worked successfully

from Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

Comment: u should never hard code the connection terrible idea

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Found out that I needed to add the context class as a service to the builder in Program.cs. In my case I am using the InMemoryDatabase option

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<WebshopContext>(opt =>
opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("AccountRequestList"));
```